# Python/Django: Issues assigning values to a list

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am trying to assign the output of `random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES)` to a list and then subsequently remove it from `PATH_ONE_IMAGES` so that it can no longer be selected. This is then meant to be returned along with other variables to the user via a `get_context_data` method, part of Djangos SesionWizardView.

I don't think what I'm attempting is that hard but I have met with a few issues.

**views.py**

```
PATH_ONE_IMAGES = ['P1D1.jpg', 'P2D2.jpg', 'P3D3.jpg', 'P4D4.jpg']

class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):                      
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
        context = super(SurveyWizardOne, self).get_context_data(form, **kwargs)  
        if self.steps.current in ['5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16']:

            images = [] 
            step = int(self.steps.current)

            if step in (5, 6, 7):
                images[step - 5] = image = random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES)          
                PATH_ONE_IMAGES.remove(image)
                context['display_image'] = image

            elif step == 8:
                context['first_image'] = images[0]
                context['second_image'] = images[1]
                context['third_image'] = images[2] 

            steps = ['5','6','7','9','10','11','13','14','15']              

            context.update({'steps': steps})
        return context
```

You can see in the above that when the user gets to step 5 the list images, at position 0 (5-5) is called image and takes the value of `random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES)`. This is then removed from the original list and the display_image, which is shown to the user, takes the value of image. Then when the user gets to step 8 they are then shown all three images again. I hope this explains what I'm trying to do.

All of my isses seem to be with the line

```
images[step - 5] = image = random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES)
```

In the above version I get the error

```
Exception Value: list assignment index out of range
```

Based on other questions I have tried

```
            images.append[step - 5] = image = random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES)          
            images.insert[step - 5] = image = random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES)
```

But both give me the error

> Exception Value:  'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support
>   item assignment

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**Update** ---------------------------------------------------------------

```
        if step in (5, 6, 7):                 
            image = random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES)   
            images.insert(step - 5, image)        

            #===============================================================
            # image = random.choice(PATH_ONE_IMAGES) 
            # images.append(image)        
            #===============================================================


            PATH_ONE_IMAGES.remove(image)
            context['display_image'] = image

        elif step == 8:
            context['first_image'] = images[0]
            context['second_image'] = images[1]
            context['third_image'] = images[2]
```

Using either insert or append results in the same error at `context['first_image'] = images[0]`

> Exception Value:   list index out of range

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what the problem is - that should be `images.append(obj)` or `images.insert(index, obj)` - note parentheses, not square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
images.append[step - 5] = image      
images.insert[step - 5] = image
```

are syntactically **incorrect**.

`append()` and `insert()` are functions. Use them like this (with parenthesis instead of brackets):

```
images.append(image)        
images.insert(step - 5, image)
```

Comment: Hi, when I use either of these methods I get an error for one of the following lines `context['first_image'] = images[0]` saying "Exception Value: list index out of range". Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `insert()` or `append()` before `context['first_image'] = images[0]`? Because if you put `insert()` or `append()` in your if-clause then it won't get called => at `context['first_image'] = images[0]` your list `images` would still be an empty list.

Comment: The code is exactly as above except with your recommended changes on how to correctly use `append` and `insert` I get the same error using either. Surely it is possible to populate the list in steps 5, 6 and 7. and access it when the users is at step 9.

Comment: You have to modify your code a bit to get it to work. Because for example if `step == 8` then you're accessing `images[0]` etc. **but** images is an empty list (`images = []`). You could store your `image`-variable in `context` and then retrieve it from there for future steps. At the moment at every step `images` is set to an empty list.

Comment: Solved it. I simply had to move `images = []` outside the top level if statement so that the list was not being created each time. Declaring at the top of my file outside any function or class worked. Thanks for all your help